# G additive group isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^{n}, \mathbf{Z}^{m}$

Tags: ring-theory

I have been stuck with this problem for quite a while now:

> G is an additive group with $n,m \in \mathbf{N}$ ; $\mathbf{Z}^{n}, \mathbf{Z}^{m}$ isomorphic. Then it holds that: $\#(G/2G) = 2^{n} = 2^{m}$. Show also that m=n without using Theorem 2.1 (or a later one).

I wanted to show the cardinality first by arguing with equivalence classes: $\mathbf{Z}^{n} = \mathbf{Z}\times \cdots \mathbf{Z}$.  Let $G= \mathbf{Z}x_{1} \times \mathbf{Z}x_{2}\times\cdots \times \mathbf{Z}x_{n}$ , $2G= 2\mathbf{Z}x_{1} \times 2\mathbf{Z}x_{2}\times \cdots\times 2\mathbf{Z}x_{n}$

So then by taking: $G/2G= \mathbf{Z}x_{1}/2\mathbf{Z}x_{1}\times\cdots\times \mathbf{Z}x_{n} /2\mathbf{Z}x_{n}$

I think that every "factor" adds 2 equivalence classes (because I know that $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} = \{\tilde{0},\tilde{1}\}$, but I have no clue how to show that there aren't any duplicates in the product. Theorem 2.1 states that if R is an integral domain, then if there are  $R^{n}, R^{m}$ which are isomorphic, $m=n$ holds.

Does anybody know how to show that there aren't any duplicates while showing the cardinality? Also how to show that $m=n$ without using any theorem? Merci

Comment: Note that $G/2G$ is actually a vector space over the field $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$. Vector spaces have dimensions that play by very nice rules.

Comment: What exactly does "Theorem 2.1" say? And what happened to $z$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Theorem 2.1: If R is an integral domain, where $n.m \in \mathbf{Z}^{n}, \mathbf{Z}^{m}$ isomorphic, then $m=n$.

Comment: What is $R$, in that statement?

Comment: It's not explicitly mentioned, only that it is an integral domain… But I assume it to be a ring.

Comment: @VVV: Integral domains *are* special kinds of rings. The question is, why is $R$ mentioned, if the conclusion is about $\mathbf{Z}^n$ and $\mathbf{Z}^m$? Or did you miscopy and it was meant to be "If $R$ is an integral domain, and $R^n$ and $R^m$ are isomorphic, then $n=m$"?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, Yes, you are right. I am a dumbhead.

Comment: "miscopied"$\neq$"dumbhead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you want to show that if $\mathbf{Z}^n\cong\mathbf{Z}^m$, as additive groups (with $\mathbf{Z}$ being the additive group of integers), then $n=m$.

One route is the one given in the statement. There are a couple of ways of showing it.

First:

**Claim 1.** If $G$ is abelian, and $G=H\times K$, then for any positive integer $n$ we have $nG=nH\times nK$.

*Proof.* If $(nh,nk)\in nH\times nK$, then since $(nh,nk) = n(h,k)\in nG$ we have that $(nh,nk)\in nG$. Conversely, if $(x,y)\in nG$, then $(x,y) = n(h,k) = (nh,nk)$ for some $h\in H$, $k\in K$, so $(x,y)\in nH\times nK$.

**Claim 2.** If $G = H\times K$, $M\triangleleft H$, and $N\triangleleft K$, then $M\times N\triangleleft G$, and $G/(M\times N) \cong (H/M)\times (K/N)$.

*Sketch.* Consider the map $G\to (H/M)\times (K/N)$ given by $\varphi(x,y) = (xM,yN)$. Prove that this is an onto group homomorphism. By the Isomorphism Theorems, 
$$\frac{G}{\mathrm{ker}(\varphi)} \cong \frac{H}{M}\times \frac{K}{N}.$$
Prove that $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi) = M\times N$ to complete the proof.

Now show that the above claims hold for any number of finite factors (in fact, they hold for *any* number of factors, finite or infinite). Together they will show that $G/2G\cong (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^n$ and $G/2G\cong (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^m$.

So, if $G\cong\mathbf{Z}^n$ and $G\cong\mathbf{Z}^m$, then applying the ideas above it follows that on the one hand you have $G/2G$ has $2^n$ elements, and on the other that it has $2^m$ elements. But $G/2G$ does not depend on *how* you write $G$, it just depends on $G$. So we must have $2^n=2^m$.

---

The following is just basic combinatorics:

If $A$ has $k$ elements and $B$ has $\ell$ elements, then $A\times B$ has $k\ell$ elements:

*Proof.* The number of elements in $A\times B$ is the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. There are $k$ possibilities for the first entry, $\ell$ possibilities for the second entry, so by the Multiplication Rule, the total number of possibilities is $k\times \ell = k\ell$.

By induction, if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are all finite, then
$$|A_1\times\cdots\times A_n| = |A_1|\times\cdots\times |A_n|.$$

(In fact, for possibly infinite sets, one *defines* the product of the cardinalities to be the cardinality of the cartesian product, $|A|\cdot|B|=|A\times B|$)

So if $A_i = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for each $i$, then since $|\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}|=2$...

Comment: These claims appear later in a similar form, I don't think they are allowed to be used…. Thank you, though.

Comment: @VVV: You could *prove* them, instead of just using them. In any case, you are invoking/using/proving that $G/2G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times\cdots\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, and your only problem is the cardinality of this product, that's a **set theory** issue: $|A\times B| = |A|\times|B|$: just *count* the ordered pairs.

Comment: Merci!…………………………………….